# Rotating drawLine Java Applet

Tags: java

I created a Java Applet which has a graph that is a parabola but my parabola is upside down? How can I rotate my drawLine?

What I extended and implemented:

```
public class Parabola extends Applet implements AdjustmentListener {

    //bunch of my code is in here ...

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        //bunch of my code in here ...

        for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++) {                           
            y1 = (int)(p[i] * 100) + 100;
            y2 = (int)(p[i+1] * 100) + 100;              
            g.drawLine(i + 20, y1, (i + 1) + 20, y2); //its upside down, needs to be rotated                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When drawing in java (0,0) in the top left point, (maxX, maxY) is the bottom right point.

Comment: @StephaneM But how does that rotate my graph?

Comment: @StephaneM My parabola is upside down and I need it to be rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out from [this](http://www.codemiles.com/java/line-rotation-2d-t105.html) website -- it's bascially trigonometry.

But, if there is an easier way, please do share.

We use:

```
X2 =X1*cos(theta)-Y1*sin(theta);
Y2 =X1*sin(theta)+Y1*cos(theta);
```

Original line:

```
g.drawLine(200,200,x1+200,200-y1);
```

Rotated line:

```
g.drawLine(200,200,x2+200,200-y2);
```